# Can GNU Make recognise multiple matches in a pattern?

Tags: gnu-make

I have a rule in a makefile like this:

```
%.120.png : %.svg
    inkscape -z -e $@ -w 120 -h 120 $<
```

which works as intended. I would like to rewrite this in a more generic fashion, something like this:

```
%.%2.png : %.svg
        inkscape -z -e $@ -w %2 -h %1 $<
```

where `%2` is a second match (`%` being the first).

As far as I know, this isn't supported.  However, if it is, how ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple patterns.  In the example you give, though, it's not hard to automate the recipe, although you'll still have to write multiple patterns:

```
INKSCAPECMD = inkscape -z -e $@ -w $(patsubst $*.%.png,%,$@) -h $* $<

%.120.png : %.svg
        $(INKSCAPECMD)
%.100.png : %.svg
        $(INKSCAPECMD)
```

Etc.  Except, looking at it more I'm pretty sure your description is wrong and that this pattern won't do what you really want

Comment: I used multiple patterns in the end, but I used `foreach` to generate them.